# repo sync duration and how to resume sync?

Tags: repository, git

I am on Ubuntu 14.0.4 and I am trying to build a CWM recovery for Celkon Q 500 (android 4.4.2, Broadcom processor).

I have set up build environment and currently working on syncing repo. I have heard that it takes too much time and disk space to complete this process.

I am interested to know in the following particular scenario : want to build only CWM recovery from source for an android running on version 4.4.2.

So do I have to download all repositories or is there any shortcut that would enable me to not download all, but a certain part that is required for android 4.4.2? If yes, how to go about it? please help.